# generate SQL script for data and unique FK names

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have many DBs with identity structures and need to have init data to each. I created script for adding init data and this script has following strings:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__aspnet_Pr__UserI__68487DD7]
```

but each my DB has different name of contraints. Can I create DBs with the same name of contraints? I tried to create DB by script, by schema compare of Visual Studio 2010 etc

I use MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can name the constraint yourself when creating it - then you should have the same name of constraint on all your databases. Since you've not mentioned anything about the schema I can't give you the exact answer - but the syntax for naming your FK when you create it is like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Profile]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyFKNameHere] FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
    REFERENCES [dbo].[OtherTable](UserID)
```

Then to drop it on all your databases is the same script:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_MyFKNameHere]
```